# Slack API - Render the messages after formatting

Tags: slack-api

I am building a slack client to get messages from Slack and render in HTML page. I have to format the messages like `*bold*` to `<b>bold</b>` html format.

I can find many libraries to convert to slack markdown but not anything to convert from slack markdown to HTML.

Is there any library or code to do this already available?

Comment: If you want to build your own its not that hard. You just need a little regex and to follow this instruction from Slack on how to do it: https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#retrieving-messages